# Locking down an Android device?

Tags: security, device-administrator

I'm interested in locking down an Android, so the user can only access a particular app (bonus points: only allow them to access the browser app, and only allow one website from within that).

How might I go about doing this with minimal work?

(I work for a school, and am considering using some androids as roll-marking devices)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of apps in the market that allow access to apps only after inputting a password.

For your second problem, i hope there's some way of preventing a user from putting a SIM of choice (either by encasing the device in a lockable case or something) and then configuring your WiFi router to only allow access to the site in question and block all other requests.